# Seeking Guidance on Error Handling and Routing

Tags: javascript, error-handling, ejs, middleware

I would like to request a review of my app.js file (Clone Project Bootcamp) to ensure that I have implemented error handling correctly. Below is the relevant portion of my app.js code:

```
const express = require ('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate');
const catchAsync = require('./utils/catchAsync');
const ExpressError = require('./utils/ExpressError');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const Campground = require('./models/campground');


const app = express();

app.engine ('ejs', ejsMate)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));


main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/yelp-camp');

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home')
})

  app.get('/campgrounds', catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const campgrounds = await Campground.find({});
    res.render('campgrounds/index', {campgrounds})
}));

app.get('/campgrounds/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('campgrounds/new');
})

app.post('/campgrounds',  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.body.campground) throw new ExpressError('Invalid Campground Data', 400);
    const campground = new Campground(req.body.campground);
    
    await campground.save();
    res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`)
        
}))

app.get("/campgrounds/:id", catchAsync(async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id);
    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error('Page Not Found!');
    }
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id);
    res.render("campgrounds/show", { campground });
}));

app.get('/campgrounds/:id/edit', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id)
    res.render('campgrounds/edit', { campground});
}));

app.put('/campgrounds/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const{id} = req.params;
    const campground = await Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body.campground });
    res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`)
});

app.delete('/campgrounds/:id', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params;
    await Campground.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    res.redirect('/campgrounds');

}));

}

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
    next(new ExpressError('Page Not Found', 404))
})



app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const { statusCode = 500, message = 'Something went wrong' } = err;
    if (!err.message) err.message = 'Something went wrong';
    res.status(statusCode).render('error', { err });
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000')
})
```

I am particularly concerned about the error handling middleware using app.use, as I am not sure if it's handling errors properly. I have noticed that since implementing this middleware, I can no longer access routes, and I always receive a StatusCode 400. It seems that the middleware is not functioning as expected, and my error.ejs template is not rendering error messages as alerts on my webpages.

Could someone please review my code and provide feedback on whether the error handling is correctly implemented or if any improvements are needed? Additionally, I am facing issues with app.all preventing route access, and I would appreciate guidance on resolving this matter. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Error Handling: I have implemented error handling using middleware in my app.js file. However, I am uncertain if this implementation is correct. Specifically, I am not sure if the error handling middleware, defined using app.use, is handling errors as expected. There is an issue where error messages are not rendering correctly in my error.ejs template.

Routing Issues: I have observed that after implementing the error handling middleware, I am no longer able to access routes as intended. Instead, I consistently receive a StatusCode 400 error. This issue seems to be related to the use of app.all.

I kindly request a review of my code and any feedback or recommendations to resolve these concerns. Any assistance in addressing the error handling and routing issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!